# Error Handling In Lua

Tags: error-handling, lua, assert

I would like to do logic like:

```
local function create(...)
    for k, v in ipairs{...} do
       if k == "player" then
           _player = v
       end
    end
    if _player == nil then
         **error**("It nil") -- stop running here and throw the error
    end
end
```

Does Lua has anything like error function here?

Comment: In this code `k` will never be the string `player`. The first value returned by `ipairs` is a numeric index.

Comment: @Etan Reisner, Get it, so can I use pairs() for ... here? Otherwise is there a way to pass string key?

Comment: How are you intending the `create` function to be called? `create("player", arg1, arg2, arg2)`? `create({player = "something", attr1 = val1, attr2 = val2})`?

Comment: @EtanReisner the 2nd one

Comment: Then you are only getting one argument so using `...` is unhelpful. You should use `pairs` to iterate over the first argument to your function. `local function create(ctab) for k, v in pairs(ctab) do ...... end`. Also remember to use locals in your function (for things like `_player`).

Comment: @EtanReisner got it. I considered ... as table

Comment: `...` is a list that's why you needed to convert it to a table by wrapping it in `{}` for `ipairs` to work.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is, and its name is exactly [`error()`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-error):

```
if _player == nil then
     error("It nil") -- stop running here and throw the error
end
```

`error()` takes a string argument for error message and an optional argument for level, it terminates the program when called.

Comment: Except if caller uses pcall or xpcall to call function that calls error, then caller can process error, no exit.